# spring reactor and boot dependency

Tags: spring, project-reactor

Is boot a prerequisite to run spring reactor? 
I am trying to use spring reactor in a regular web application environment. I can see that the reactor configuration is created.  Consumers are registered. Notifications are called. Events are NOT fired. What and how to check?

Configuration

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableReactor
    public class ReactorConfiguration {
        @Bean
        Environment env() {
            return new Environment();
        }

        @Bean
        Reactor createReactor(Environment env) {
            return Reactors.reactor().env(env).dispatcher(Environment.THREAD_POOL)
                    .get();
        }


    }
```

Registering consumers:

```
@PostConstruct
public void onStartUp() {
    logger.debug("Registering Consumers");
    reactor.on(Selectors.T(Envelope.class), processParentRequest());
    reactor.on(Selectors.T(Bundle.class), processOptimizerRequest());

    reactor.on(Selectors.$(Constants.LOWER_ASG), processLowerAsgsRequest());
    reactor.on(Selectors.$(constants.SET_CONSUMPTION_LEVEL),
            processConsumersRequest());
    reactor.on(Selectors.$(constants.SET_GENERATION_LEVEL),
            processProducersRequest());
    reactor.on(Selectors.$(constants.SET_STORAGE_SUPPLY_LEVEL),
            processStoragesRequest());
}

private Consumer<Event<Envelope>> processParentRequest() {
    return envelope -> optimizerUpdatingService
            .processParentRequest(envelope);
}

private Consumer<Event<Bundle>> processOptimizerRequest() {
    return bundle -> eventProcessingDispenser
            .processOptimizerRequest(bundle);
}

private Consumer<Event<Envelope>> processLowerAsgsRequest() {
    return envelope -> lowerAsgsProcessingService
            .processLowerAsgRequest(envelope);
}

private Consumer<Event<Message>> processConsumersRequest() {
    return message -> consumersProcessingService
            .processConsumersRequest(message);
}

private Consumer<Event<Message>> processProducersRequest() {
    return message -> producersProcessingService
            .processProducersRequest(message);
}

private Consumer<Event<Message>> processStoragesRequest() {
    return message -> storageProcessingService
            .processStoragesRequest(message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot is not a pre-requisite at all, it simply provides some conveniences when using Spring with Reactor.

There could be any number of things happening. Without any details it's hard to give specific suggestions.

Comment: The log says:[ConsumerBeanAutoConfiguration] reactorConversionService has not been found in the context. Skipping.

Comment: The case is solved. It had internal errors not related to the Reactor configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is NO.
Spring boot is not a pre requisite but it makes your bootstrapping easy.

All you need is [project reactor](https://projectreactor.io/docs) in your classpath to use reactor